# How is a procedure application a control structure?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages, language-design

In scheme, a procedure application is considered as a control structure. Why is this?

Comment: What is your source for this? Where have you looked for an explanation? [That tag had nothing to do at all with your question...[

Answer (score 2):

The answer will depend on how you define "control structure", for which there are probably $n+1$ versions out there.

My best guess is this. Control structures *change* the control flow of the program from just incrementing the program counter. In usual machine-level languages, this is implemented using *jumps*.

Calls to functions/procedures/methods compile to jumps, among other things. Hence, they change the control flow, and we can call them "control structure".